Why do we actually use the subjunctive in languages like Spanish?
I am aware of when to use it; that is not my question. Why do we say "Sugiero que vayas" rather than "Sugiero que vas" when it is clear that the latter would express the meaning just as clearly? I understand it's not the indicative form, but I don't see the need for separate endings. Can anyone explains why?

Why does Spanish use yo suigero / tú sugieres / él sugiere when (the equivalent of) yo sugiere / tú sugiere / él sugiere works just fine in many other languages? Why does it have genders? Why does it have a difference between imperfect and preterite? When it comes to language, ‘why’ questions like these are often not answerable in any really meaningful way. Things are the way they are because that’s how they evolved over time, and there’s no particular logical reason for that.

Wouldn't it better to ask this on the Spanish site where everyone knows Spanish? It's because the Spanish consider it un verbo de influencia, all of which take subjunctive: https://www.rae.es/gtg/verbo-de-influencia https://www.rae.es/gtg/verbo-de-influencia

Verbo con el que se solicita, induce o fuerza una acción, un proceso o un comportamiento, como en Le han ordenado {regresar ~ que regrese}; Les prohibieron hacer fotos; A verb used to request, induce or force an action, process or behavior as in: They ordered him to return. They prohibited them from taking pictures.

@JanusBahsJacquet that makes sense, thanks

@JanusBahsJacquet I think this is a bad example. The reason Spanish uses it is well known: it's inherited from Latin. In Latin, the difference between a subjunctive and an indicative is immediately clear, and the use of one over the other in many constructions completely changes the meaning.

@cmw The same is true of all the other examples I gave. Spanish has personal endings, genders and a difference between imperfect and preterite because Latin did (well, imperfect and perfect in Latin, slightly altered in Spanish). And Latin had it because PIE had it (again, with some alterations). The difference between an indicative and a subjunctive is also immediately clear in Spanish, but the reason why this difference is expressed using a subjunctive mood in particular (rather than, say, modal verbs or particles) is not answerable.

But you answered why. The reason why Spanish uses subjunctive instead of modals here is because it inherited the subjunctive from Latin. Latin does not have modals to express what the subjunctive expresses here. Anything else is overcomplicating it. (Sorry for the typos. I'm typing on my phone for this comment.)

@cmw ohhhh, ok, thank you. i was suspecting it was something to do with that until i read the comments, thanks for the help
